# Want to access android location services in a leaflet.js project running in a webview

Tags: leaflet, gps, android, geolocation

I am running leaflet.js project on my android app using a webview. Everything is great but for current user location leaflet uses GPS because it runs in a webview and as we know webview is extention of browser on android. Now GPS is not very reliable. I want to access android sensors of accelerometer or geomagnetic sensor to determine user position not GPS. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: "for current user location leaflet uses GPS because it runs in a webview and as we know webview is extention of browser on android". The underlying Android operating system is feeding that webview if you are using the HTML5 API for location... are you seeing something different?

Comment: I am using the geolocation api leaflet provides. I am recovering user location using map.locate(). Don't know if leaflet uses HTML 5 api in underlying architecture or not. But when I use my map in webview,the location does turn on and starts tracking but I don't see the location setting in android turned on. Neither I get any sort of warning that you usually get when trying to run an app that requires location service.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation